# Expose an enum from Models in ViewModel in C#

Tags: c#, mvvm, enums, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I have a Xamarin project that's composed of a Models project, a ViewModels project, and a "View" project for each platform the app is to be released on. The Models project is linked to the View Models project, but is not (directly) used by the Views projects.

The problem is that I have a pair of enums in the Models project that I'd like to use in the Views, without linking the Views projects to the Model. Is there some way to expose these enum types to View?

What I'm doing now is copying/pasting and then type-casting the Model enums into identical enums in the ViewModel, but that feels hack-ish and could break something if a new enum was added to the Model but not the ViewModel. Is there a better solution, besides creating a new constants/enums project that we link all the others to?

What I'd like to do:

```
//MODEL Project
enum MyEnum{
    enum1,
    enum2
}
class ModelObject{
    MyEnum status;
}

//VIEWMODEL Project
class VMObject{
    MyEnum status = modelObject.status;
}

//VIEW Project
if(vmObject.status == MyEnum.enum1){
    //...
}
```

What I currently do:

```
//MODEL Project
enum MyEnum{
    enum1,
    enum2
}
class ModelObject{
    MyEnum status;
}

//VIEWMODEL Project
enum MyVMEnum{
    enum1,
    enum2
}
class VMObject{
    MyVMEnum status = (MyVMEnum)modelObject.status;
}
//VIEW Project
if(vmObject.status == MyVMEnum.enum1){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't the view know of the models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this should fall under the responsibility of the ViewModel. The whole point of the ViewModel is to transform your model domain into something the view domain is able to digest. IF this means making a new enum then so be it. This is where automapper helps.

On a side note. I find using an enum, from outside of the view-domain, to be a bit of an bad pattern anyway, as it brings logic into the view. Personally I don't expose the view to knowing anything (directly) about the enum types. If I need to have the view change behaviour due to a specific enum value, then I have that logic in the ViewModel.

Update:

You goal for the View should be to remove any and all business logic. So in your case, you are saying you want the view to change its icon based on some model state. The issue you seem to be facing is you don't want the view to have direct access to the model enum type. So don't, and reverse your thinking around. Have a View that uses its own enum:

```
enum ViewIcons
{ 
    IconOne,
    IconTwo,
}
```

... which, from your your `ViewModel` can be set

```
view.Icon = ViewIcons.IconOne
```

So lets say in your ViewModel you do an update

```
void Update()
{
    switch(_model.State)
    { 
        case ModelState.Inactive: 
            view.Icon = ViewIcons.IconOne 
...
```

Why do it this way? Well, if you remove your model domain completely and replace it with something different (think about that), you only have to refactor your ViewModel domain. Your View domain classes are non-the-wiser.

Comment: The reason we use the enums is because they tell the View which icon to display next to different objects, and the ViewModel doesn't know about the icons.

Comment: The alternative is to reverse it around. Create a View-domain enum that defines your cases. The ViewModel then maps between them `View.IconState = Automapper.Map<ViewIconState>(_modalStatus)`. Again, The whole point of the MVVM design is to have ViewModel bridge Model and View, as such it should be aware of both domains without exposing them to each another .

Comment: So, to make sure I understand, this still requires duplicating the enum from the Model to the ViewModel? In this case how is Automapper superior to a straight Typecast?
(Also in your answer I believe you want a single = in CanSave = _status == ...)

Comment: I've updated. No, you're not duplicating an enum. You are separating out your view concern. the view's enum can be different to the model's enum and its the job of the viewmodel to transform between them.

Comment: Well, in that case, our implementation is almost the same concept as yours. It just turns out that our selection of icons perfectly matches the enumerations in the Model, so the duplication/typecast accomplishes the same thing. I'll mark your answer correct since it is technically the right thing to do.

For the record, what I had wanted was actually to expose the Models enum to the View (as a shortcut to this), but if the View and Model are supposed to be separate like this, I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Add them to a fourth project called `Common` or `Shared` or something like that. This isn't an uncommon problem, and that's how I've always tackled it.